# Technical explanation of how creating and displaying youtube annotations works?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, youtube, annotations, flex3

I will soon begin working on a school project that involves the use of real-time annotations in videos.  I really like the way youtube's annotation system works and am really curious to learn how they created it.  And more specifically, figuring out how to reproduce the main components of their functionality.

If you expand the main points, this link covers a high level of what's possible with annotations.
http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?answer=92710

**Would anyone be able to provide a technical explanation of how this system of creating and displaying annotations works?** (Ex.  A database stores the start time of an annotation, the end time of an annotation, the text block of the annotation, and a unique numeric identifier for the annotation. When a video reaches the start time of an annotation it's displayed until the end time.)

More specifically does anyone know what tools were used to created this system?  Was flex used or was it done in purely in something like flash professional?

I found it difficult to read up on any technical details about annotations.  The youtube actionscript 3.0 api documentation doesn't mention annotations

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference.html

Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it won't matter what development environment was used, but I'd recommend doing any sort of advanced Flash development in FlashBuilder/Flex.

Secondly, the YouTube api is for third-party developers to access features of the YouTube platform, you won't find any special hidden info about how the YouTube product has been developed.

Anyway, let's have a look at how annotations work.

1. They need to be created by end-users, so they need to have a forgiving, easy to use creation/edit method.
2. They need to be quickly provided for each video when it's requested, so a structured text file containing the meta data for the annotations is the best fit (XML perhaps due to the Flash E4X technology, or JSON, since there are adequate JSON libs for Flash too.) These structured text files are probably stored in a database (likely a NoSQL type solution.)

As for the format of the meta-data, you need an on/off cue, coordinates, style, message text, and perhaps a click-through link. Use the YouTube video annotator and make a note of all the things you can do when adding/editing annotations, then you have a list of all the things that the meta-data needs to store.

Flash video allows the use of cue points embedded in the FLV, so these can be used to link to the custom meta-data and display the appropriate annotation in the coordinate/style/text for that specific cue on. Similarly, when a cue point that corresponds to an annotation's cue-off, we can then remove it from the display.

This is a fairly rudimentary overview, leave a comment for things you want me to expand on, also I'm not covering every possible way that YouTube implements it's different types of annotations, for example, speech bubbles; ignoring cue-close for annotations which have been closed; spotlights etc etc, but when you are building a simple annotation system you can ignore these extra details for your first version.

#### References:

- [Flash Video events](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/VideoEvent.html)
- [Flash Video cue points](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSD30FA424-950E-43ba-96C8-99B926943FE7.html)

#### Additional references:

- [Flash SoundChannel docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html#eventSummary)

Comment: First off wow, thanks so much.  I just wanted to say I really appreciate your detailed answer.  The thoroughness and quickness of your response was impressive and very helpful.

Comment: I have very basic experience with c++, php, mysql, javascript.  I once made a very basic membership based website from scratch with those languages where users could do very basic things like log in and post stuff.

I have never touched actionscript, or flash.  Right now I'm on my 2nd day of trialing adobe flashbuilder.  How do you recommend is the best/quickest way I can learn the ropes before I hop into this project? I'm going through the "Flex in a week" tutorial right now http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html

Comment: Also, I thought it may help to mention that this project is for music analysis.  So instead of there being annotations superimposed over a playing video there probably will be some flash-based mp3 player with a textbox next to it that generates dynamic content as the song is playing

Comment: @LedZeppelin - it's important to note that MP3 playback in Flash doesn't support *native* cue points, in the way that FLV playback does, so you'd need to implement that as a custom feature. You can see where the playhead is in time, so instead you'd have a listener setup for each **EnterFrame** event, and then check where the playhead is, lookup the annotations, see if there's a matching cue point, if so... display (or tear-down, if it's an "off" cue point.)

Comment: @LedZeppelin - in terms of getting started see if you can get going with a simple `SoundChannel` playback of an mp3 and setup a single cue point, and see if you can have it reported when the playhead hits it. Just do the cue point as a `Number` variable, the `position` property of the `SoundChannel` is also a number, so you just need to see them match. Once you've got that going, it should be fairly straightforward to extrapolate to multiple annotation points.

Comment: @LedZeppelin - With regard to creating the user interface to add the annotations / cue points, look at how soundcloud.com lets people add comments to a track. They approximate the position of the annotation to the visual representation of the waveform, and turn off the annotation after a second or two, instead of an explicit "off" cue point. It all depends how you choose to design and implement the user interface, but it's a decent example.

Comment: @LedZepplin - Have a look at http://mattshaw.org/news/as3-mp3-player/ in particular the `updateProgress()` and `play()` methods, note that the `EVENT_TIME_CHANGE` is managed by a `setInterval(updateProgress, 30);` (i.e. updated every 30ms.) This is an alternative strategy to using `ENTERFRAME` and is worth being aware of, it will generally provide better results (since the update time will be tighter). Much of the code here is useful for you too.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your effort in helping me out.  You have a lot of great ideas that I'm going to explore.  Thanks for all the links and resources.

Comment: Here's a quick (probably dirty, I didn't compile it.) example of using that Mp3Player class with a set of predefined cues/annotations. https://gist.github.com/1210454

Comment: @LedZeppelin - happy to help, have fun.